# What tags should be avoided, and why?

Tags: discussion, tags

To prevent the tagging system from becoming a mess, let's assemble a list of tags that are a bad idea, and what the suggested good alternatives are.

One topic per answer, please.

Answer (score 4):

[clipboard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clipboard) is an overloaded term. Instead, use [os-clipboard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-clipboard) for questions about interacting with the operating system's clipboard or [register](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/register) for vi registers.

Comment: I'd suggest synonymizing [tag:clipboard]->[tag:register], since the name "register" may not be that much recognized. A good tag excerpt would then help people realize which one of them they want.

Answer (score 3):

[movement](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movement) and [navigation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation) are too vague.  Instead, use

- [cursor-movement](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cursor-movement) if the question involves moving the cursor
- [scrolling](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrolling) if it involves scrolling the text
- [tags](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) for the tag navigation system
- [filesystem](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem) for navigating through the filesystem

Comment: Navigation can also mean navigating the filesystem through vim (unless `:cd` is the only way to do so?)

Comment: @muru `:Explore`

Answer (score 3):

Does [tab](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tab) (or [tabs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabs)) refer to the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, tab-indentation, or tabs in de UI?

- [tab-key](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tab-key) for the tab key.
- [tab-indentation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tab-indentation) or just [indentation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation) for tab indentation
- [tabbed-user-interface](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabbed-user-interface) for ui tabs

Comment: Why would tab indentation need its own tag? [tag:indentation] should cover the topic.

Comment: @200_success It doesn't "need" it, in most cases indentation should be good, but you could ask a question specifically about tab indentation...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker `tab-indentation` synonymized to `indentation`?

Comment: @200_success Indenting with tabs vs spaces is a common and distinctive enough subproblem to warrant its own tag, distinct from configuring the amount of identation, defining indentation rules for a new language, automatic indent settings, etc. On the other hand, I don't see [tag:tab-key] as being relevant: what makes it different from other keys?

Comment: @Gilles To me, indentation is just one topic. [tag:whitespace] could be another topic worthy of a tag, for discussion tabs-vs-spaces, invisible characters, etc. But I don't think that [tag:tab-indentation] would be a beneficial tag.

Comment: @200_success Indeed [tag:tab-character] would be a better name.

Answer (score 3):

[help](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help), because "help" is the point of the site. I can already see it being used by people "needing help". Better to use [help-system](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help-system) if you have a question about Vim's `:help`.